# Android Wear heart rate sensor raw light data

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

Is it possible to record the raw light data from the heart rate sensor in Android Wear? I know it's possible to record the calculated heart rate in bpm, but I would like to record the raw light data.

The device I am using is the Polar M600.

This question has been asked before, but I am asking it again in case any new devices or APIs have made access to this data possible since then:

[Read underlying color/light data from Android Wear heart rate sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308542/read-underlying-color-light-data-from-android-wear-heart-rate-sensor)

[How to access Android Heart Rate Sensor RAW DATA? (reflected light, not the heart beat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534659/how-to-access-android-heart-rate-sensor-raw-data-reflected-light-not-the-hear)

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what data is shown but on the moto360 sport you can see other information from the heartrate sensor. Using [wearSensors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.waynepiekarski.wearsensors&hl=en) you scroll though each sensor on the watch. See if has anything none standard, in the sport case a motorola.sensor.ppg sensor. [image]